# Multiply matrix by vector row-wise

Tags: rust, nalgebra

How can I multiply a matrix and a vector "row-wise" in nalgebra? Like I would do in numpy

```
>>> m = np.eye(3)
>>> v = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> m * v  # Or v * m
# Gives [[1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 2, 0],
#        [0, 0, 3]]
```

What I tried:

- `dot` is doing the "real" math operation (outputting a vector)
- `m * v` or `v * m` doesn't work because it wants either 2 matrices or 2 vectors
- `component_mul` requires the same number of elements

Note: I know that I can convert my vector into a matrix and use other operations, but my goal is to avoid useless work.

Comment: So how exactly do you want the operation to look?

Comment: I thought there would be a single function call or an operator. Writing 2 loops for this operations is ugly and slow.

Comment: I'm not sure if `nalgebra` provides an built-in operator or function for element-wise multiplication between a matrix and a vector

Comment: Kindly post your answer if you find one

Comment: @Nil "_Writing two loops for this operation is_ […] _slow._" → No it isn't, even if such a function exists in `nalgebra` it will be implemented as those exact same loops and so will have the exact same speed (minus the function call overhead, which would point in favour of the explicit two loops if it wasn't negligible).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to know what *numpy* calulates. In both cases `v * m` or `m * v`, if I multiply a vector by the identity matrix, the result is that vector:
eg. `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]`

```
let m = DMatrix::<f32>::identity(3, 3);
let v = DMatrix::<f32>::from_row_slice(1, 3, &[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]);
println!("{:?}", v * m);
let m = DMatrix::<f32>::identity(3, 3);
let v = DMatrix::<f32>::from_row_slice(3, 1, &[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]);
println!("{:?}", m * v);
```

---

The straight-forward method *to write the vector elements directly into the matrix* would only need one loop:

```
let mut m = DMatrix::<f32>::zeros(3, 3);
let mut pos = 0;
for n in [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] {           //[[1, 0, 0],
    m.get_mut(pos).map(|f| *f = n);  // [0, 2, 0],
    pos += 4;  // rows + 1           // [0, 0, 3]]
}
println!("{:?}", m);
```